# Fire angular function from on click of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using an angular library called ng-swippy. I'm building a tinder-like interface. What I want to do is if someone clicks a heart, it would fire the same functionality as swiping right. And if someone clicks the "X", it would fire the same functionality as swiping left.

URL: http://430designs.com/xperience/black-label-app/deck.php

I have a click function called clickLike() (line 214) fired on ng-click. Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('black-label', ['ngTouch', 'ngSwippy'])
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $timeout, $window) {
    $scope.cardsCollection = [
      {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_01.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_02.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_03.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_04.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_05.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/thor_06.jpg',
          collection: 'thoroughbred',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_01.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_02.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_03.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_04.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_05.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/rhap_06.jpg',
          collection: 'rhapsody',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_01.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_02.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_03.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_04.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_05.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cha_06.jpg',
          collection: 'chalet',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_01.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_02.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_03.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_04.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_05.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/mod_06.jpg',
          collection: 'modern',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_01.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_02.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_03.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_04.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_05.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/ind_06.jpg',
          collection: 'indulgence',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_01.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_02.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_03.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_04.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_05.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/cnt_06.jpg',
          collection: 'center-stage',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_01.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_02.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_03.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_04.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_05.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, {
          thumbnail: 'images/deck/vin_06.jpg',
          collection: 'vineyard',
      }, 
    ];
    // Do the shuffle
    var shuffleArray = function(array) {
        var m = array.length,
            t, i;
        // While there remain elements to shuffle
        while (m) {
            // Pick a remaining element
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
            // And swap it with the current element.
            t = array[m];
            array[m] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }
        return array;
    };
    $scope.deck = shuffleArray($scope.cardsCollection);

    $scope.myCustomFunction = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.clickedTimes = $scope.clickedTimes + 1;
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Click on item' });
      });
    }; //end myCustomFunction

    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.showinfo = false;
    $scope.clickedTimes = 0;
    $scope.actions = [];
    $scope.picks = [];
    var counterRight = 0;
    var counterLeft = 0;
    var newVar = $scope;
    $scope.swipeend = function() {
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Collection Empty' });
        $window.location.href = 'theme-default.php';
    }; //endswipeend

    $scope.swipeLeft = function(person) {
        //Essentially do nothing
        $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Left swipe' });
        $('.circle.x').addClass('dislike');
        $('.circle.x').removeClass('dislike');
        $(this).each(function() {
            return counterLeft++;
        });
    }; //end swipeLeft

    $scope.swipeRight = function(person) {
      $scope.actions.unshift({ name: 'Right swipe' });
      // Count the number of right swipes
      $(this).each(function() {
          return counterRight++;
      });

      $scope.picks.push(person.collection);
      // Checking the circles
      $('.circle').each(function() {
          if (!$(this).hasClass('checked')) {
              $(this).addClass('checked');
              return false;
          }
      });
      $('.icon-like').addClass('liked');
      $('.icon-like').removeClass('liked');
      if (counterRight === 4) {
          // Calculate and store the frequency of each swipe
          var frequency = $scope.picks.reduce(function(frequency, swipe) {
              var sofar = frequency[swipe];
              if (!sofar) {
                  frequency[swipe] = 1;
              } else {
                  frequency[swipe] = frequency[swipe] + 1;
              }
              return frequency;
          }, {});
          var max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(frequency)); // most frequent
          // find key for the most frequent value
          var winner =Object.keys(frequency).find(function (element) { return frequency[element] == max; });
          $window.location.href = 'theme-' + winner + '.php';
      } //end 4 swipes
    }; //end swipeRight

    $scope.clickLike = function() {
      $currentTarget.toggleClass('happy');
    }; //clickLike
});
```

I can get the click to fire, but I'm losing the object `person` that I need to pass to it. I need to pass thatI hope that makes sense. I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now and can't seem to get an answer.

Thanks in advance. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: We don't mix jQuery operations into AngularJS.  Your swipeLeft and swipeRight are implemented in jQuery.

Comment: Can you set $scope.person somewhere in the controller and then `$scope.clickLike= function() { $scope.swipeRight($scope.person); }`?

Comment: I'm definitely learning this very quickly. However, `$scope.person` isn't available until a swipe function has been called. That's the issue I'm having. The `person` object isn't available anywhere in $scope until you swipe right or left.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thank you or clarifying. So `ng-swippy` must provide api to swipe left and swipe right. The attribute `swipe-right=swipeRight(person)`  is only call back after swiping occurred. Looking at their source code https://github.com/B1naryStudio/ng-swippy/blob/master/ng-swippy.js I don;t see any means to programatically swipe.

Comment: The other option is to raise those mouse down/touch event sequences on clickLike and clickDislike. I suggest you try that and create a plunkr - we can help improvise.

Comment: I did see someone asked about swiping programatically. What do you mean by raise the mouse down/touch events on the clickLike? I have the plunkr made, but getting some errors. http://embed.plnkr.co/CnvCVBIlNeH2RkWuj60N/

Comment: I improved your plnkr a bit but there are too many dependencies images etc required https://plnkr.co/edit/vWWqtYTLg4mBbktTW6jp?p=preview

Comment: You can do things like `angular.element('#myelement').trigger('touchstart')` you may need other events as well. This is going to be complicated path. I see that you have modified the ng-swippy.js for card-tpl. In that case you can even add swipe.moveRight and swipe.moveLeft but that is beyond the scope of this question/format.

Comment: Thank you very much for that @bhantol. So I just implemented that line above, but I get a jqLite error when I do it. I tried doing things (like toggling a class) before, however, I always get an error. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130628/discussion-between-lz430-and-bhantol).

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I always use a service or factory, to pass data :

```
angular.module('main').service('passDataService', function () {
var DataList = [];    

var setObjectData = function (Data) {
    DataList.push(Data);
};

var getObjectData = function () {
    return DataList;
};

var resetObjectData = function () {
    DataList = [];       
};


return {
    setObjectData : setObjectData ,
    getObjectData : getObjectData ,
    resetObjectData : resetObjectData 
};

});
```

in your controller add **passDataService** as dependency and set/get data, like:

```
passDataService.setObjectData (yourData); //Set
var getObject = passDataService.getObjectData (); //get
```

this way you can always keep and pass your data no matter which controller you are or what methods you calling.

Comment: I really like this idea. However, I'm relatively new to Angular in general. I'm not sure exactly how I would get the `person` object, since it's not available to just any function. Only the 2 swipe functions. The library I'm using has it setup this way.

Comment: This will not work. For what @lz430 wants to achieve is to actually swipe the things as if a user swiped it manually.